# How do I get the selected item from a ListView by opening the context actions menu? (Xamarin.Forms)

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

When I tap on an item in the ListView, it highlights orange and becomes the SelectedItem, which I can then use in my context actions menu code. However, when I long-press to open the Context Actions menu, it does not select the ListView item that I've long-pressed and still assumes the last item selected from the ListView (i.e. the one I tapped before) is the SelectedItem.

How can I get the selected item that I long-press? I am using the most recent version of Xamarin.Forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you just pass on the clicked ListItem using the CommandParameter:

```
    <MenuItem Clicked="OnMore"
                  CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                  Text="More" />
```

Once you do that you simply get the command parameter something like:

```
 public void OnMore (object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    var commandParam= ((MenuItem)sender).CommandParameter;   
 }
```

Using the above example you will get the selected model value